# Using Regex to search for a word before a given word

Tags: php, regex, search, match, icalendar

I am slowly piecing together an implementation of class.iCalReader.php, to take an iCal feed and produce a table with all the events that are going on in a building on a particular day. As part of that, I need to extract which room the events are going to be in - this is contained within the 'Description' field of the iCal array.

So, I've established I need to use regex to look in description for the word 'room', and then return the word before 'room'. However, the actual regex eludes me - I'm not a great programmer.

Currently I have:

```
function getRoom($description, $search = 'Room')
{

if (1 !== preg_match('#\s(\w+)\s+('.$search.')\s#i', $description, $matches)) return 'TBA';
return $matches[1];

}
```

where I set the variable `$search` to 'Room' in the call to the function. There can be more than one room.

The .ical stream contains, as part of its' array of events, the following:

```
DESCRIPTION:Event Type: Private\n\nRegistrations: 1 \n\nResources: Indian Room
```

I then get this once it's been parsed by class.iCalReader.php using this line:

```
$description = $event['DESCRIPTION'];
```

Later on in my php, I set $room as so:

```
$room = getRoom($description);
```

Then, I try and return the value using:

```
if ($room !== FALSE) {
    echo "<td>". stripslashes($room) ."</td>";
} else {
    echo "<td>No Room Allocated</td>";
}
```

Any suggestions as to where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Could you some examples of `$description`?

Comment: It's called lookahead, http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html , probably append (?=room) to your expr.

Comment: Yes - so, the description comes from each event like so: '$description = $event['DESCRIPTION'];'

This produces a result in the array that might look like this: **DESCRIPTION:Event Type: Private\n\nRegistrations: 1 \n\nResources: Indian 
 Room**

Comment: Sorry, the array contains **DESCRIPTION:Event Type: Private\n\nRegistrations: 1 \n\nResources: Indian 
 Room**, and actually, this is 'decoded' by class.iCalReader.php into everything after the first :, so Event Type: Private\n\nRegistrations: 1 \n\nResources: Indian Room in this case.

Comment: Please, edit the question to add what you gave in comment.

Comment: Hi M42, That's done, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check: http://regex101.com/r/jJ5mU7/3

You may need to remove the first # or is it something php specific?

You need lookahead with ?=

You need non-greedy matching part (with 2 rooms): a question mark after the +

Change to

```
if (1 !== preg_match('\s(\w+)\s+?(?='.$search.')\s', $description, $matches)) return 'TBA';
```

with a focus on the ? and the ?=

Comment: Hi Pieter21,
I've just tried this and it still returns TBA as the result for everything.
I'm going to read through the Regex tutorial you linked to, but for now, this doesn't seem to behave as expected.

Comment: Give a few examples of your input please in your question.

Comment: Ok, I've added a load more info into the question - I can post the full code, but it might be too much!

Comment: I've just tried that - I can see it works on your regex101 link, but not in my code. I had to add delimiters for it to work, so the expression became 'if (1 !== preg_match('#\s(\w+)\s+?(?=Room)\s#', $description, $matches)) return 'TBA';'
Should I assume perhaps that I have a problem passing the correct string to it, as the expression obviously works?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
'#\s(\w+)\s+('.$search.')\s#s'
```

or

> '#\s(\w+)\s+('.$search.')\s#is'

```
if ( preg_match('#\s(\w+)\s+('.$search.')\s#s', $description, $matches))
  return $matches[1];
else 
  return 'TBA';
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Again, that doesn't work. I'm starting to think that somewhere along the line, it's not getting the $description for each event - I'm going to look into my code in a bit more detail.

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to sort it, with your help! It wasn't processing the description properly, however, this has done the trick:

```
    function getRoom($description, $search = 'Room')
{
    $description .= ' ';
    if (1 !== preg_match('#\s((\w+)\s+Room)[\s.;]#i', $description, $matches)) return 'TBA';
    return $matches[1];
}
```

Thanks guys!